# Get an error to get custom taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Here this code for get wordpress custom post taxonomy terms and link-

```
<?php 
    $topic= get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');
    foreach ($topic as $topics) {
       $topiclink = $topics->name;
       $link= get_term_link($topics, 'product_cat');
       echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$topiclink.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

But Found an error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...."

Answer (score 0):

Ok ( the 10 second solution ),

```
 $topic= get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');
 if( $topic ){
   foreach ($topic as $topics) {
       $topiclink = $topics->name;
       $link= get_term_link($topics, 'product_cat');
       echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$topiclink.'</a>';
    }
 }
```

Read the documentation next time.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

specifically this bit.

> Return #Return
>
> (array|false|WP_Error) Array of term objects on success, false if there are no terms or the post does not exist, WP_Error on failure.

You cannot loop on `False` a boolean value.  This would indicate that there are no terms of `product_cat`.

Comment: pls check my questions- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560652/my-taxonomy-taxonomy-php-page-post-not-show

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with either $topic or $topics.

```
<?php
$topic= get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');
 if( $topic ){
   foreach ($topic as $topics) {
       $topiclink = $topics->name;
       $link= get_term_link($topics, 'product_cat');
       echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$topiclink.'</a>';
    }
 }
?>
```